# Using 'this' in nested function in class

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested function parameters and 'this' context in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139471/nested-function-parameters-and-this-context-in-javascript)

I'm currently having problems to design my JS classes as desired due to a problem using 'this' in a nested class function call. Don't know how to describe it better so here's a sample what I mean.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="main" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function doIt() {
            var myTestClass = new TestClass();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="doIt();">Do it!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```
function TestClass() {
   // this is working
   this.alertValue('This works');

   // this is not working
   setTimeout(function(){this.alertValue('This does not work!')}, 1000);
}

TestClass.prototype.alertValue = function(value) {
   alert('Value is: ' + value);
}
```

Of course this is just a simplified example to demonstrate the problem I mean.
So how could I use the 'this' identifier within the function inside the setTimeout call or how would be a better / the correct way to achieve that?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!
Cheers

Comment: this question seems to be asked a dozen times every day

Comment: It's important to know that `this` is set (or "reset" if you will) on **every** function call.

Comment: Sorry to ask such a common question but I honestly searched for an answer before posting but the problem in finding the right answer was that all keywords are much generic :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the value of `this` in a variable (`self`) and then you can access it within `setTimeout`.

```
function TestClass() {
   this.alertValue('This works');
   var self = this;
   setTimeout(function() { 
     self.alertValue('This does not work!')
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest something more descriptive than `self`, though.  Perhaps `testClass` would be useful.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: Hi, it's just a *convention* used by many libraries, such as `jQuery`, to name `self` the cached reference to the instance.

Comment: Understood.  I disagree with the convention.  What do you do if you nest another level, `self2`?!  Using a more descriptive name is IMHO much more useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that immediately answer!

Comment: @ScottSauyet: I understand your point, but I'd prefer not to have more than one nested level; it can be quite confusing.

Comment: @João - That confusion is often my world, I'm afraid, with many levels of callbacks, handled through whatever mechanism.  But even in simpler environments, `self` is less descriptive than `this`, which we at least know is bound to the _closest_ scope.  If the function were not immediately invoked in a `setTimeout` but instead returned to be called later, the link to what `self` meant at the time the function was created could be quite tenuous.  Hence my preference for a descriptive name.